# Is it possible to make the server accessible from two internet connections

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

how to make this:

[image]

have:

- Centos 6.5
- WAN1 eth0 44.44.44.44 (DEFROUTE=yes)
- WAN2 ppp0 95.95.95.95 (DEFROUTE=no)
- HTTP server work and available only in eth0
- DNS server work but port 53 blocked in eth0
- ping available only in eth0
- client can access through eth0 to HTTP and PING
- ISP block port 53 in eth0
- ISP block port 80 in ppp0

need:

- client PC must can access PING both eth0 and ppp0
- client PC must can stay access to HTTP in eth0
- client PC must can access to DNS in ppp0

I try make this but did not understand until the end how to do it:

```
echo 2 ppp0_OUT >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 95.95.95.95 dev ppp0 table ppp0_OUT
iptables -A PREROUTING -i ppp0 -t mangle -j MARK --set-mark 2
ip rule add fwmark 2 table ppp0_OUT
ip route flush cache

sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ppp0.rp_filter=0
```

---

question:

1) How to make that the client PC could access the server at the same time via eth1 and via ppp0

2) client PC must have acces to DNS via ppp0 and to HTTP via eth0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is wery simple answer :)

just need:

- if Client PC connect via WAN1 he must get answer via WAN1
- if Client PC connect via WAN2 he must get answer via WAN2

answer:
WAN1 have options **DEFROUTE=yes** and when WAN1 start he was:

```
# ip route 
....
default via 44.44.44.44 dev eth0  proto static
```

WAN2 **NOT have default route!!!** we need create default route for WAN2
it simple script for do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
###
# echo 202 out_ppp0 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route flush table out_ppp0
ip rule del table out_ppp0
IP_ppp0=$(/sbin/ifconfig ppp0  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')

ip rule add from $IP_ppp0 table out_ppp0
ip route add default via $IP_ppp0 dev ppp0 table out_ppp0
```